# How can the below code be integrated into a RecyclerView Adapter for deleting files?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

i am trying to create a video player app for android, i am trying to add delete functon in my app, so can you tell me how to add this code in recyclerview adapter class, i dont know how to use resultLauncer in activity , please chechk the code :-

```
private lateinit var intentSenderLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest>

 intentSenderLauncher =
            registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()) {
                if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Video deleted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "Video couldn't be deleted successfully",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }

            }


suspend fun deleteFile(uri: Uri) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                contentResolver.delete(uri, null, null)
            } catch (e: SecurityException) {
                val intentSender = when {
                    Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R -> {
                        MediaStore.createDeleteRequest(contentResolver, listOf(uri)).intentSender
                    }
                    Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q -> {
                        val recoverableSecurityException = e as? RecoverableSecurityException
                        recoverableSecurityException?.userAction?.actionIntent?.intentSender
                    }
                    else -> null
                }
                intentSender.let { sender ->
                    intentSenderLauncher.launch(
                        IntentSenderRequest.Builder(sender!!).build()
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How can i use resultLauncher in Adapter , beacuse i have button in adpter to delete the file

Comment: It's not good for encapsulation to try to use classes like this in your Adapter. It's the Single Responsibility Principle of object oriented programming. Treat your adapter like its only task is to connect UI to data. Expose callback(s) in the adapter that are called when clicks are made. The Activity or Fragment can decide what to do by implementing the callbacks.

Comment: Than how i add delete feature in on delete buttons beacuse without MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE delete function not work than i am trying use this function to take permission on every video deletetion process but this function not also work in adapter, any anther way present to delete file